# Purpose of struct.unpack

Tags: python, struct, floating-point, binary, unpack

I have been trying to figure this out for some time now and i get nowhere.
I have two unsigned integers. This means four bytes.

```
3A BC 00 00
```

These represent a float value. I want to convert them to float using python.
I can do this with python using `struct.unpack`.

Specifically:

```
values = [0x3A, 0xBC, 0x00, 0x00]
struct.unpack('>f', bytes(values))
```

Can someone explain this particular `unpack` command?

I know that the `>` part reverses the bits (big endian implementation). So they will be `00 00 BC 3A`.
What does `f` does? According to the docs it means float... What does this mean? I tried omitting it but i got `struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 0 bytes`

Finally, why the casting to `bytes` happen?

Comment: Specifying endianness changes the order of bytes, not individual bits.

Comment: *"I have two unsigned integers. This means four bytes."* - well not really, depends on the size of one integer... *"the > part reverses the bits"* - the bytes actually, but no, it keeps them as is, with `3a` as most significant byte. *Little endian* would instead reverse them, using `00` as most significant byte. *"What does f does"* I'd suggest to read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html). *"why the casting to bytes happen"* - because `struct.unpack` wants a bytes-like object, i.e. `bytes` or `bytearray`.

Comment: @sj95126 You are corrected, i edited the question.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thanks! I have read teh documentation, but do not understand the `f` part...

Comment: The `f` says to treat the 4 bytes as a floating-point number, rather than an integer, or an ASCII string, or one of the other possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `struct` module deals with conversion between python objects and a contiguous sequence of bytes. `[0x3A, 0xBC, 0x00, 0x00]` is a list of python integers (that is, references to `int` objects), not a contiguous sequence of bytes. A `bytes` object is a contiguous sequence of bytes and can be initialized with an iterable of integers between 0 and 255, so that's the first step.

Now, how should python interpret these bytes? Are they an integer, a bunch of floats, a bunch of characters? That's what the format string is for. `"f"` means "grab me a 4 byte float". The ">" is big-endian as you note, but its a bit more subtle. Python will grab 4 bytes, *then* deal with the endianness, and finally do the float conversion. Suppose the input was `[0x3A, 0xBC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44]`? The format ">ff" would return 2 floats.

Finally, that's not "two integers". Its a sign bit, 8 bit exponent and 23 bit mantissa which is a standard format for single precision floats.

Comment: [`>` is actually big-endian](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) not little-endian.

Comment: @MarkRansom - thanks, don't know how I scrambled that when typing.